# How do you convert a timestamp format within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, format

how do I convert something like
`2020-12-01T15%3A48%3A39.862Z`
to a timestamp format of
`2018-09-15T15%3A53%3A00-07%3A00`?

I am not very familiar with timestamp formats and manipulation of datetime in Javascript...

Comment: The timestamp in JavaScript is expressed in milliseconds, can you please elaborate a bit more, can you share some code which you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into a DateTime directly, you just have to decode all that `%3A` stuff first:

```js
var timeString = '2020-12-01T15%3A48%3A39.862Z';
var decodedTimestring = decodeURIComponent(timeString);
var date = new Date(decodedTimestring);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Just as a sidecomment, the library `moment` is probably the most popular library to make it easier to deal with DateTimes in javascript, both inside the browser and in node.js